# how to control Router settings by a flutter application (not in a WebView)

Tags: flutter, dart, network-programming

i am building an application for Android by using flutter and dart for changing routers settings like password and username and shows user on the networks .etc.. with an easy interface for the user I don't wanna show the hole webpage from the router settings .but i wanna deal with some settings by using the widgets in flutter to send data like user name .. password ..etc
i hope someone understand what i meant .. thanks for reading

i searched but i didn't find what i need yet
..new to flutter  and programming

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

the only way to do it is to communicate with the router page via http, http_io
and use the HTTP requests and responses to deal with the info and make login first and deal with the json or xml response type.
I'm now making a one for my router(zte ZXHN H188A) and successfully connect to my router and load the info of it, i am now making my ui that i will use to present the data